# THREE.js position updates are suspended while web worker is active

Tags: javascript, three.js, worker

I have a sphere in a THREE.js scene. I update its position every step of the animation/rendering loop.  It works fine and the sphere moves smoothly.

However when I activate a simple web worker from the main script the THREE.js scene stops updating for periods exceeding 10 seconds.  I can force jerky scene updates by repeated mouse clicking on the display container.

The web worker doesn't do anything fancy, it just iterates through a couple of for loops and sends a message back to the main script on each step of the outer loop.

Please can anyone suggest a solution to get the THREE.js updates to proceed smoothly despite the web worker activities?

====

EDIT

It appears that worker was sending messages too frequently for the main thread to keep up. Not a THREE.js problem.

The solution was to amend the worker so that the time interval between messages reaching the main thread was reduced.  This was done by either (a) inserting a time delay between posting messages (suitable when no message information can be discarded) or (b) to  only send 1 in N messages (which is suitable when sending position updates for animation).

A possible alternative solution would be for the main thread message handler to fully process only a limited number of the messages received e.g. (i) according to the type of information in the message or (ii) according to the current load and desired throughput.

All these solutions require manual tuning by trial and error to find a mechanism which suitable for the job in hand.